# Can I get all block header data like the SPV node?

Tags: blockchain, hash, python, spv, block-header

It hasn't been long since I studied Blockchain.

I only need header data, not all block data, for study purposes.

As far as I know, the SPV node stores only the block's header information.

Can i get all block header data in python?

Comment: You can run a node (https://bitcoincore.org/) and use the `getblockheader` RPC command.

Comment: Can't I download it with python code?

Comment: You can use a wrapper against it RPC API, such as https://github.com/petertodd/python-bitcoinlib. Note that you'll have to wait for `bitcoind` to sync (can take anywhere from some hours to a week depending on your hardware).